# How to convert from PDF to TXT without unintended line breaks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf, pdfminer

I am trying to convert a very clean PDF file into txt file using python. I have tried using pyPDF2 and PDFMiner, both worked perfectly in text recognition.

However, as in PDF the lines are wrapped, the extracted .txt file have unintended line break at the end: e.g line 1: "is an account of the Elder /n Days, ". There should not be a line break between the "Elder" and the "days".

[image: txt file]

The PDF file:
[image]

When edited with Acrobat, it can be clearly seen the original text in PDF contains no hard line break, and could be edited as a paragraph instead of single lines.
[image]

The Code I have tried (adapted from an answer from here: [convert from pdf to text: lines and words are broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55220455/convert-from-pdf-to-text-lines-and-words-are-broken))

```
import io as io
from io import StringIO
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
import os
import sys, getopt

#converts pdf, returns its text content as a string
def convert(fname, pages=None):
    if not pages:
        pagenums = set()
    else:
        pagenums = set(pages)

    output = io.StringIO()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)

    infile = open(fname, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    infile.close()
    converter.close()
    text = output.getvalue()
    output.close
    return text

path='D:\Folder\File.pdf'
a=convert(path)
f=open("D:\Folder\File.txt",'a',encoding='utf-8')
f.write(a)
f.close()
```

Comment: The .pdf file itself is formatted that way? In line 1 for example, you can clearly see the line break from "Elder" to "Days".

Comment: @Yes, the .pdf file is in presented in this way because any given paragraph needs to end somewhere instead of appear as a very long single line. However, when I try to edit this on Acrobat, it actually returns as a paragraph, instead of single lines. Hence I'm pretty sure the line is just wrapped, not broken.

Comment: Can you simply strip single line breaks as it appears as though you want to keep double line breaks?

Comment: @JonSG　Thanks for commenting. There are other single line breaks in the doc that I want to keep, so I'm looking for a universal solution. 
Also I saw many discussions online on how to extract from PDF without the line breaks  and it seem to be a long existing problem for many. So I think it would be of interest to others too. There are softwares that enables this feature, but I'm wondering whether it could be achieved on python.

Comment: I'm better we can do something. Python aside, how would you determine when to keep or discard a line break?

Comment: @JonSG So let's say I created 2 word docs, A.doc with a long paragraph that only appear as multiple lines because of line wrapping, and B.doc where I hard broke the paragraph into separate lines by pressing 'enter' (which will give me a line break). After that I saved both A and B as pdf. I am hoping to extract text and get back the same from A.pdf and B.pdf - A as a paragraph and B as multiple lines.  I've seen one solution online - to export PDF from Acrobat Pro to html, so that there are no line breaks in A.htm. But I'm wondering if it can be done in python, as not all PCs have Acrobat Pro

Comment: But aren't one-line breaks in the original document equal to two line-breaks? And the ending of a normal line transfers to a one-line break (the ones you'd like to remove). Thus by stripping one line-break per line should solve the issue, doesn't it?

Comment: @J.M.Arnold.  I understand what you mean. I've only shown a small portion of a 180+ page PDF. There are portion where it doesn't follow this "1 line breaks in the original document equal to 2 line-break" pattern, where there 1 line break might equal to 1 line break or more line breaks. ), as they have different spacing between paragraphs.

Comment: You are misdiagnosing what Acrobat is doing.  A PDF file is just a capture of a printout.  It does not have the concept of paragraphs and sentences, nor does it do any wordwrapping.  It's just "print this string at this X,Y coordinate", for each line.  There definitely ARE line breaks at the end of each line.  Acrobat is just guessing that those lines make up a paragraph because of the positioning.   You need to do the same thing, manually.

Answer (score 2):

"A picture is worth a thousand words" and comments do not allow pictures! I am using the Web archive of a different copy but the Gist is exactly the same.

You are working with "justified" content but unlike reflowing justification in a word processor, the glyphs are generally tied to a line of a set position up from the page base. Adobe are working on reflowable PDFs and have the expertise to combine lines in a paragraph, however other readers will accept`</br>`

 each line for what it is. `</br>`

`<p style=indented>`There are no paragraph boundary markers, like there is in say HTML `</p>`

Readers could in the future be augmented like Acrobat, to combine the lines, but it's not needed for reading (aloud) one line at a time. Some audio readers will noticeably stutter on those "line at a time" returns, whilst some are intelligently programmed to simply ignore them.

[image]

In short you need to add your own AI/regex to gather lines and add indents, but beware significant human literature differences such as hyphenation and oriental punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

## if you have the lines in ASCII, just with extra \n's

In this situation, the simplest strategy would probably be to remove all *single* line breaks transforming them to a single whitespace, and transform *double* line breaks to paragraph breaks.

This appears to work with your example.

Doublebreak - short sequence -doublebreak (e.g. "\n\n    * * *\n\n") might also be present.

Otherwise, probably the double line breaks, once white space-trimmed, are preceded by a full stop.

## if you have a text with no clear line breaks, or line and paragraph breaks are the same

In this case the text extraction tool you have will return one long line of text, or a single line break for paragraphs too. The linebreak and paragraphing information is kept in the PDF in the form of text coordinates.

**Such a tool will not work for you.**

Here, you need a way of *retrieving* the text flow information. One such tool is PDF2JSON (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40671828/1428679); the code is PHP, the algorithm is the same. The tool is not the best suited for your case, but the algorithm may offer insights). If you do yourself the word building, then:

- if the y-distance between two characters is above LineHeight, that's a new line
- on the same line, introduce spaces when the distance between one character and the next is above WordThreshold.
- you insert line breaks when line is longer than the margin distance less a reasonable threshold, if the text is justified; or not, if the length of the first word on a line is less than the space still available on the line before.
- Finally, you insert paragraph breaks when a character has a y-distance above ParagraphThreshold from the previous character

The above rules can be tuned to the specific case.

**In Python you should be well served by PyMuPDF plus Unidecode**, using the "blocks" option. The word-building described above is already done by PyMuPDF.

Comment: @KJ based on this quote, "e.g line 1: "is an account of the Elder /n Days,", I expect that this is no problem, as *someone* did extract the lines. However, I'll amend the answer.

Comment: @KJ I do have some experience with PDF internals; the text extractor in the answer I linked happens to be mine. I even ended up (after several years of essentially reinventing my wheels while extracting text from various PDF collections in my line of work) developing a tool to automate the creation of PDF text extractors (unfortunately, in C).

Comment: @KY Yes, exactly. That's essentially what was described in the (new) second part of my own answer. You can't discard the positioning information early, which means that the OP's text extractor cannot be used directly.